# new learner trying to get floting button

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Center(
    child:Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icon.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('hello world'),
    ) ,
      body: const Center(child: Text('hello guys'),),
      ),

  ));

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxUGj.png)

Comment: can someone help me on this code guys ??

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
   home: Center(
   child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: const Text('hello world'),
    ),
    body: const Center(
      child: Text('hello guys'),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {},
     ),
    ),
   ),
 ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. refer [**`FloatingActionButton`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('hello world'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('hello guys'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanx my guy 

Comment: If your problem has been solved by my answer please mark it

Comment: it fixed my friend thanx you my guy (: